# How do I use Stellar API to power my Universal Trading and Multicurrency Payment+Transacton Gateway?

Tags: transactions, development, protocol, ripple-gateways, stellar

I am planning to build on top of Stellar a unified universal gateway+trading platform(all frequencies) for banks and financial institutions to power ultrafast international payment transfers in fiat/crypto currencies, automated equity and forex trading as well as interbank transactions involving trade financing instruments e.g. Conditional Lines of Credit, LCs and Bank Guarantees. I plan to write its low-latency backend in C++ and frontend will comprise of a PID server in combination with a web/JavaScript site as GUI.

The PID server monitors the PID’s of the strategies/transactions running on the server and executes the commands as they come. The server could consist of a webserver listening on port 8888 with a simple JSON interface, to make it super flexible.

How do I use Stellar API to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by reading the concepts here so you know what stellar will do for you vs what you have to do on your own: https://www.stellar.org/developers/learn/
It also has the API documentation.

Comment: the link is broken

Answer (score 1):

A platform for realtime international payments would definitely be possible using the [Stellar API](https://www.stellar.org/developers/).

You'd need to first [become a gateway](https://www.stellar.org/developers/learn/integration-guides/gateway.html) on the Stellar network. More on what it means to be a Stellar gateway [here](https://www.stellar.org/developers/learn/concepts/assets.html).

I'd also recommend familiarizing yourself with the [Javascript SDK](https://www.stellar.org/developers/js-stellar-sdk/learn/index.html), which lets you integrate a web app (that you build) with the [Horizon API server](https://www.stellar.org/developers/reference/).

If you have have more questions about integration with the Stellar network, feel free to join [slack.stellar.org](http://slack.stellar.org) and chat with developers from Stellar.org team and the global Stellar community. It may be easier to help you with the development process if we can chat in real-time.